# Issue with dynamic component presentation DD4T 2.0

Tags: componentpresentation, dynamic-publishing, dd4t-2

we have upgraded to dd4t 2.0 recently. Now i'm facing issue in getting dynamic component presentation using component presentation factory.

i'm using ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentation(ComponentUri, TemplateUri)

the issue is it's fetching the component presentation successfully but the component template properties are null except template i'd, other properties like title, metadata etc are null.

As I don't see anyone raising this issue previously, I'm assuming issue is with our set up. Can anyone guide me where and what items i need to check to figure out the issue.

also, if anyone else faced this issue and resolved already please share the details of fix here.